# How choose the number of classes of a series?

Tags: classification, data-visualization, partitioning

I am newbie in DS.

I'm doing a choropleth map with votes of a senator in several cities.

And I have two questions:

1 - How choose the correct number of classes to part the data?
At the time im using four classes, but not for a specific reason.

2 - How choose the technique to use to create these partitions? I saw there are some like natural breaks, quantiles, standart deviation etc, but I don't know how and why to use.

The data looks like this.

| city | votes |
| --- | --- |
| city_1 | 1k |
| city_1 | 23k |
| city_1 | 57k |
| city_1 | 112k |
| . |  |
| . |  |
| . |  |
| city_n | 500k |

Could you point me the theory around this?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

**It sounds like you might be interested in the literature on cartography and, more generally, data visualization.**  The former explicitly addresses questions of [choropleth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) (area-filled) maps.

Among the considerations in any such work are

- Purpose: Why do you want to draw this map?  What message should it convey?
- Audience: To whom do you wish to communicate?
- Psychology: What are the ways in which maps and statistical graphics communicate information?

  - How do people derive meaning from graphics?
  - What methods of symbolization lend themselves to faster and more accurate understanding?
- Statistics: To what extent do the data suggest forms of visualization and grouping of the values?  What are suitable ways of expressing and re-expressing data for visualization?

The classic reference is Jacques Bertin, [*Semiology of Graphics.*](https://www.esri.com/en-us/esri-press/browse/semiology-of-graphics-diagrams-networks-maps)  It contains extensive (thousands) of examples organized by a few basic principles.

A modern study of the psychological aspects is [Allen MacEachren,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_MacEachren) *How Maps Work.*  It is difficult reading but provides rewarding insight.

Another classic work is [William Cleveland,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_S._Cleveland) *Visualizing Data.*  Cleveland's group at Bell Labs conducted psychological studies aimed at obtaining scientific answers to these basic questions, leading to practical advice for constructing statistical graphics (and, incidentally, maps).